# Library photos as source to UIImage

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

How to give images in photo library and camera as source to UIImage

```
/* On button click i want to save image */
myImage = /*What i have to give here to take camera or library images*/
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self,
    @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the question you asked previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309540/uiimage-as-photolibrary-file-or-camera

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) object.  It will present the modal view that allows either taking a picture or selecting an image from the device library.  You should also become familiar with the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol.  With these two, it is easy to interact with both the camera and on-device library.